# Get all manufacturers for a particular store

Tags: magento

The following code gets me all the manufacturers in all my stores:

```
$attribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->addStoreFilter($storeId)->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'manufacturer');
if ($attribute->usesSource()) {
    $options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);
}
```

However I have multiple stores and I only want the manufacturers for my chosen store id.

I've tried adding store filters to this but with no luck.

Any one have any ideas how to filter this by store?

Answer (score 1):

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();    

$attributes = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_collection')
    ->setStoreId($storeId);
    ->setEntityTypeFilter($product->getResource()->getTypeId())
    ->addFieldToFilter('attribute_code', 'manufacturer') // This can be changed to any attribute code
    ->load(false);


$attribute = $attributes->getFirstItem()->setEntity($product->getResource());

/* @var $attribute Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute */
$manufacturers = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);
return $manufacturers;
```

This should do it.  You can lower the attribute to select on.

```
 $product    = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
 $products   = $product->setStoreId($storeId)->getCollection()
                 ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'price', 'small_image','short_description','manufacturer'), 'inner');

        $this->setProductCollection($products);
```

Comment: Thanks but that gives me the following error: Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage_Eav_Model_Mysql4_Entity_Attribute_Collection::addStoreFilter(). Any thoughts?

Comment: I added setStoreId instead of addStoreFilter, please try now.  If that doesn't work, your going to need to change the collection that we are working on.  I will add another option.

Comment: Thanks but I couldn't get that to work either. TBH I think the processing time on this may be too heavy as I was going to put it on the homepage. Think I'll end up manually adding the manufacturers. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

See this blog post: http://www.sharpdotinc.com/mdost/2009/04/06/magento-getting-product-attributes-values-and-labels/

Go to the section labled "How to get Only the Attribute Values that have been used on products"

Answer (score 0):

I got the list of manufacturer from the current store using product count

```
    public function getAllManu()
{
  $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
  $attributes = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_collection')
              ->setEntityTypeFilter($product->getResource()->getTypeId())
              ->addFieldToFilter('attribute_code', 'manufacturer'); //can be changed to any attribute
  $attribute = $attributes->getFirstItem()->setEntity($product->getResource());
  $attrMenuItems = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);

    foreach ($attrMenuItems as $key => $value) {
       $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
       $collection->addFieldToFilter(array(array('attribute' => 'manufacturer', 'eq' => $value['value'])));
       $numberOfProducts = count($collection);
       $attrMenuItems[$key]['products_count'] = $numberOfProducts;
    }   

  return $attrMenuItems;
}
```